# Laravel Fortify Return Inertia::render() instead of a blade view

Tags: laravel, fortify, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I'm currently building a SPA with vue and installed jetstream (that comes with fortify) and using inertiajs to get my vue components. Is there a way to use `inertia::render('')` when i use `Fortify::loginView()`?

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 4):

I have it working right now by requiring Intertia in the FortifyServiceProvider, and just calling an Inertia render like normal.

```
Fortify::loginView(function () {
        return Inertia::render('Login');
    })
```

Comment: Where do you exactly put this? also any instructions on how to use Inertia with Fortify? I click the login button but nothing happens when page is refeshed.

Comment: In the Fortify Service Provider, under the boot method.

Comment: Actually I found the solution. I forgot adding `HandleInertiaRequests` middleware in the kernel file. Also the code snippet you posted was not required at all, at least in my case.

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to do the same thing, but looking at the current documentation, I don't think it's possible.

https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/features/authentication.html#views